# Is it better to use device channels (sharepoint) or media queries (css) for large sharepoint sites?

Tags: css, device-channel

I am building a large sharepoint site. Visitors will use various devices to access the site. Should i use device channels to control the display of elements or would it be more advisable to use css media queries???

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi please find the explanation as below:

source - [Make SharePoint responsive - Bootstrap or media query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22929422/make-sharepoint-responsive-bootstrap-or-media-query)

> I was in the situation to choose which one i would use to implement a
>   responsive design in SP2013 and so I collected **pro's** and **con's**
>   foreach technology.
>
> ---
>
> ### Device Channels ##
>
> `Device Channels` can deliver the best performance and optimizability for the enduser and the client - in my
>   opinion :)
>
> **Pro**
>
> - individual designed `HTML/CSS` and `JS` foreach device
> - -- no need for hiding or removing incompatible elements
> - -- faster because you just load things you really need
> - -- faster because you will likely have less `CSS/JS and HTML`
> - -- faster because you can use optimized code foreach device
> - -- better you can better point out which channel has errors and changes dont affect the other channels
>
> **Con**
>
> - individual designed `HTML/CSS` and `JS` foreach device
> - -- you have to append changes to each masterpage
> - -- more work to accomplish the same result (in general)
> - -- redundancy
> - bound to `User Agent Strings`
> - growing diversity of devices
> - -- may equals growing diversity of masterpages >> work
>
> ---
>
> ### Media Queries
>
> **Pro**
>
> - only necessary `CSS`
> - no `JS` if you dont wan't to
> - you can create your own layout
> - with `response.js` even in IE6 working
> - you can easily separate which features should be available in certain screen sizes
>
> **Con**
>
> - several sets of `CSS` depending on the number of `Breakpoints`
> - every feature needs to be developed by yourself
> - it's not easy to write generic code that can process every SP2013 Page
> - -- it depends on the complexity of the content shown. I write about 150 lines of `CSS` that created a mobile view for publishing pages
>     that contained the navigation and content, but no features like
>     editing, etc.
> - -- if the client's want every feature on his smartphone, there is a hell lot of work and testing needed. (Plus who the hell wants to do
>     that on their phone?)

**My 2 cents**

I prefer the modern Responsive Web design(RWD) approach as it leads to less "headaches" in terms of dependence on UI/UX team and relatively less painful and shortened testing phase. The RWD approach i use handles the desktop, tablet and mobile devices quite well and haven't received any major complains from customers/clients.

Additional reading:

[Device channels v/s Responsive web design by Prashanth BS](http://www.slideshare.net/prashanthbs/device-channels)

[Responsive Web Design vs. Device Channels by Jean Paul](http://www.jeanpaulva.com/index.php/2014/02/21/responsive-web-design-vs-device-channels/)

[Responsive vs. Adaptive Web Design – What about Device Channels? by Stefan Bauer](http://www.n8d.at/blog/responsive-vs-adaptive-web-design-what-about-device-channels/)

[Responsive Web Design v Device Channels in SharePoint 2013](https://spmatt.wordpress.com/2014/04/28/responsive-web-design-v-device-channels-in-sharepoint-2013/)